# user login laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

can't manage to login anybody an idea? i still get redirected back to the login page

```
Route::post('login', function() {
   // get POST data
    $email = Input::get('username');
    $password = Input::get('password');
    if ( Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email,'password' => $password) ))
    {

        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
    else
    {
        // auth failure! lets go back to the login
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->with('login_errors', true);

    }

});
```

Comment: Do you have a unaltered User model? Also tell us what you have in your table. On a side note, is the password in your table hashed as the Auth hashes the password before querying.

Comment: @fl3x7 I'm in a similar situation as well. Can you elaborate your side note. that might be solution to the problem. thanks

Comment: @JeyKeu More details on hashing at: http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if ( Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email,'password' => $password) ))
```

to

```
if ( Auth::attempt(array('username' => $email,'password' => $password) ))
```

Comment: It's not necessary as per the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users)

Comment: It depends. You should use whatever column name corresponds to a "username" in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a setting that lets you specify the username as either 'username' or 'email' (or whatever else you may choose), check config. Like above indicated...

```
if ( Auth::attempt(array('username' => $email,'password' => $password) ))
```

Also, Laravel expects a hashed password by default.

Answer (score 0):

To use email as username, try adding this to User model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'email';
```

Also make sure email is the primary key on your 'user' table.