# Laravel 4 authentication not working

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4 app in which I have set up one user. In my login route I'm calling `Auth::attempt` with the email and password but it always comes back as false. I definitely have the password correct and the correct hash in the database as `Hash::check` returns true.

I think it may be due to using `email` as the login field instead of `username`, but I can't see any setting for that. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231234/authattemptcredentials-always-returns-false) implied you could add an option to `config/auth.php` but it didn't work. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814526/user-login-laravel-4) says to use `username` as the array key, but then I get SQL error because it tries to select on a username field in the database.

Do I need to add something to the User model to specify the username field? Here is my login route:

```
Route::post('login', function() {

    // data from login form
    $credentials = array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    $auth = Hash::check(Input::get('password'), Hash::make('mypass'));
    var_dump($auth); // this is TRUE

    // login was good
    $auth = Auth::attempt($credentials);
    var_dump($auth); // this is FALSE
});
```

Comment: The array key should correspond with a column that you use to authenticate users in the database. This is mentioned in the [docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users). Have you changed the default `User` model that L4 ships with?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the problem. As suggested by Jason in the comment above, I had modified the `models/User.php` file and removed some functions that I didn't realise were necessary.

The `getAuthIdentifier()` and `getAuthPassword()` methods must be included in the User model for authentication!

Comment: That they do. The model must also implement the `UserInterface` and `RemindableInterface`.

Answer (score 6):

In app/config/app.php make sure you have the 'key' set.  This made me pull my hair out.  Everything will apear to work, password seems hashed in the DB, but it will always return false until you set this key and re-hash your password into the DB.

> > > "php artisan key:generate"

Comment: Thank you so much man. I'm using Jeffery Way's Laravel 4 Generator and I totally forgot this critical point in the Laravel installation before I started coding my routes and controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and made me sweat for hours. Definitively check your **User.php** model and make sure you have not **overwritten** the default one. Thanks Jason!