# Auth::attempt changing default password to default field like in DB

Tags: database, authentication, laravel, eloquent

I have a form and I'm trying to login by using Laravels Auth method.

At the moment I have this snippet:

```
$input = Input::all();

$login = Auth::attempt([
'username' => $input['username'],
'password' => $input['password']
]);

if($login){
return "Logged in";
}

dd('problem');
```

But even after entering correct credentials I'm getting to see "problem"

in **models/User.php** I've changed my table name to tbl_login(like I have in the DB) and that is the only change I've made in it

and in my login model I have

```
class Login extends Eloquent {
protected $guarded = array();
protected $table = "tbl_login";
protected $primaryKey = "pk_loginID";

public static $rules = array();
}
```

I also checked this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181546/laravel-4-authentication-not-working) but didn't really help and I'm hoping that you guys can help me with this now.

Just as info and a sidenote: table name in Db = tbl_login

primary key field is pk_loginID

username field = username

password field = password

Did I forget something or did I do something wrong?

**EDIT:**

I've found the problem more specific, but not a solution for it. My password field in the DB has another name than the default password field that Laravel uses. How can I say to Laravel to use my custom password field?

Comment: You have both a `Login` and a `User` model linked to `tbl_login` table?

Comment: Yes, because User was standard there, but I just deleted Login model but same problem is occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution

In the `User model` in the method `getAuthPassword()`

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
     return $this->attributes['passwordFieldinYourTable'];//change the 'passwordFieldinYourTable' with the name of your field in the table
}
```

That's it :)

Comment: i have following database structure for my user table ```fld_ID, fld_Username, fld_Password``` is it possible doing the changes in User files? and how?

Comment: Helped alot. Voting up such that people who did not name their password field as "password" will know what to do.

Comment: Happy to help! @MehdiHosseini still need help with this? Just saw your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it, but you probably can fix that by creating new mutators to the password field:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    ...

    public function getPasswordAttribute()
    {
        return $this->YourPasswordField;
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->YourPasswordField = $password;
    }


}
```

Comment: I've added this methods in my user class but it is still the same actually. Nothing has changed. My field in the table for password is "PASSWORD" so I replaced `$this->YourPasswordField` to `$this->PASSWORD`