# Laravel Authentication Failing

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I have more or less worked through [this authentication tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/authentication-with-laravel-4/) that goes over basic user authentication with Laravel. Everything that I can find is in line with the tutorial, and every other article and question that I can find on the topic, but my authentication is still failing.

I have ensured that I'm using the correct email and password. You can visit [the project website's registration page](http://bonnettewedding.com/index.php/users/register) to register, and then log in if you'd like. It's currently displaying the email and password as part of the authentication's error message.

The user creation code is:

```
public function postCreate() {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            // Validation has passed, save the user in the database
            $user = new User;
            $user->username = Input::get('username');
            $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
            $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();

            return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Thanks for registering!');
        } else {
            // Validation has failed, display error messages
            return Redirect::to('users/register')->with('message', 'The following errors occurred . ' . $validator->messages())->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
    }
```

And the actual log in code is:

```
public function postSignin() {
        $credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'));

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return Redirect::to('users/dashboard');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect ' . Input::get('email') . ' ' . Input::get('password'))
                ->withInput();
        }
    }
```

The error being given when I try to log in is a simple "Your username/password combination was incorrect."

I've checked to make sure that the information going into the database is correct, even. For example, this is currently the users table:

[image: users table]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181546/laravel-4-authentication-not-working

Comment: I can post the code if necessary, but I don't believe that this is a duplicate of the above question because I have not removed or modified any methods of the User model. I also tried the `php artisan key:generate` which completed successfully. I then created a new user and attempted to log in with no success.

Comment: I didn't say it's a duplicate, I posted it if it helps you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the password field in your database is 60 characters long. password hash that Laravel generates is 60 characters